# Covert NTP string to DateTime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I wrote a function to convert date/time string in NTP to sql dataTime format. It is working perfectly.

Usage:

`SELECT dbo.udf_ntp_converter('21:21:54.715 Greece Mon Aug 24 2015')`
returns

```
2015-08-24 21:21:54
```

However my problem is that sometimes the string comes with a dot or asterisk at the beginning of the string like in the following examples:

*21:21:54.715 Greece Mon Aug 21 2015

.21:21:54.715 Greece  Mon Aug 21 2015

I don't want to use REPLACE as it might omit the millisecond separator.
How can I modify my current function to take care of that?

Here is my current function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_ntp_converter] (@TimeStamp varchar (45))

    RETURNS varchar(20)

AS

    BEGIN

        DECLARE @result varchar(20);

        SELECT @TimeStamp = REPLACE(@TimeStamp,'*','')

        SELECT @result = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), (CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(@TimeStamp, 11))+CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(@TimeStamp,12))), 120)

        RETURN @result

    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a little check for `*` and `.` at the beginning.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_ntp_converter] (@TimeStamp varchar (45))

    RETURNS varchar(20)

AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @result varchar(20);


 IF (LEFT(@TimeStamp ,1) IN ('*','.'))
     BEGIN
           SELECT @TimeStamp = RIGHT(@TimeStamp , LEN(@TimeStamp) - 1)
     END

  SELECT @result = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), (CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(@TimeStamp, 11))
                                             +CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(@TimeStamp,12))), 120)

        RETURN @result

END
```

Comment: That fixed it. In all my attempts I never used BEGIN and END inside the if statement.